# Can I ask Biology related ontology question on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, site-recommendation

I have the following question closed on Stackoverflow which I have asked on biology.stackexchange.com now but I think no one will be able to answer that because it has more to do with Ontologies than with biology itself.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890675/disease-ontology-for-disease-synonyms

Please suggest a correct place to post this question.

Comment: If your question involved code, then probably yes.  However your question as it stands had nothing to do with code at all.  From what I understand about it, you're trying to get terms for which you can use in your program.  That is not a programming problem.

Comment: @JeffMercado is biology forum a better place for it?

Comment: It _sounds_ like it's a fine place to take it, I'm not familiar with the subject at all.  If you're ever in doubt, ask in their meta, [meta.biology.se].

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is much better suited for [Healthcare IT (currently in Beta)](http://healthcareit.stackexchange.com/).  Flag to have it migrated or repost it, and we'll take it (I am a mod *pro tem* over there).

I don't think it's enough about the science to fit on the Biology site.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that no question of the form, 'where do we find an ontology' is not on topic. In fact, any question of 'where do I find data' is off-topic.